# How can I use private data fields for a class and still call them in my main?

Tags: java

My assignment says that I must use private data fields. but I can not call them in my `Main`. What am I doing wrong? I get an error in my `Main` after I try to print the `width`.

```
public class RoomDimension {
    //data fields
    private double length;

    //default constructor
    RoomDimension(){
        length = 10.0;
    }

    //overloaded constructor
    RoomDimension(double l){
        length = l;
    }

    //setters and getters
    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RoomDimension kitchen = new RoomDimension();

        System.out.println(kitchen.getLength());
    }
}
```

Comment: The code seems to be fine. Probably you should import the `RoomDimension` class if it's in another package.

Comment: (1) Please post the exception that occurs including the stack trace.  The code seems to be valid.  (2) You don’t *want* to access private fields in the main method.  Use `RoomDimension`’s accessor methods instead (as you already do for the length).

Comment: As there's no mention of width nowhere in your code it's extremely hard to figure out what might be wrong.  Btw, the way of accessing private members as shown, ie via a getter, is the way to go, also for width.

Comment: I don't understand how a question without a direct problem can be upvoted...

Comment: There seems to be a lot of arbitrary upvoting on questions. It's been happening since SO opened, and I'd love to know if it's an automatic process to encourage new users.

Comment: Discussion of upvoting patterns would be a good topic for Meta. (The system keeps pestering me to upvote more questions...)

Comment: I apologize for any inconvenience i have caused the community here. I'm a relatively new programmer and completely new to this site. I'm trying to follow rules as best I can but is also hard when all of this is new to me. I went to work on something else for a wile and came back to my program and now it seems to be fine. I wish I knew what was wrong before so I could post an answer. 

thanks guys! (how can I improve my next questions?)

Comment: Also. I have investegated my issue further and I think I had "kitchen.Length instead of Kitchen.getLength()"

Comment: @rample since it is a simply typographical error we will most likely close this question. Look at [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to figure out how to better improve your questions. Welcome to the community!